# Importing NativeModules gives me an empty object even though my native module is properly created and registered

Tags: android, react-native

I'm following [this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) to try my hand at Java usage in react-native (to then use the JNI and use C code).

I've followed all the steps, but when I'm trying to get the Native Modules in js, I'm getting an empty object :

```
//HelloWorld.js
"use strict";
import { NativeModules } from "react-native";
console.log(NativeModules); // prints "{}"
module.exports = NativeModules.HelloWorld;
```

Following is the content of my files. Note that the `android/` folder generated has been opened as a project through android-studio, and there are no errors highlighted.

**HelloWorldModule.java :**

```
package com.bridgemodules;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class HelloWorldModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    public HelloWorldModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext); //required by React Native
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "HelloWorldModule"; //HelloWorld is how this module will be referred to from React Native
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void helloWorld(Promise promise) { //this method will be called from JS by React Native
        promise.resolve("Hello World!");
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public int cloneReturn(int a) {
        return a;
    }
}
```

**HelloWorldReactPackage.java :**

```
package com.bridgemodules;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloWorldReactPackage implements ReactPackage {
    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new HelloWorldModule(reactContext)); //this is where we register our module, and any others we may later add

        return modules;
    }
}
```

Updated **MainApplication.java** file to register my module :

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
              new HelloWorldReactPackage(),
              new MainReactPackage() // Added this line
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Since I've followed the tutorial step by step, I'm a little bit surprised that this doesn't work. Note that the project was generated using `react-native-cli`. I've read online that it changed the code's structure in ways that could make things different.

Thanks in advance, I'm really stuck on this one.

Comment: Are you importing your native module in a host project as per the tutorial?

Comment: Wellp... Turns out this was the issue, @sinewave440hz. I created a new project with `react-native init programname` from scratch, re-followed the steps, and now it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: cool...I'll put in an answer to complement yours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your HelloWorld.js would typically reside in your module's index.js. Also typically, you would install your module package in the react native project in which you want to use the native module. There, you would use code something like the code sample in the tutorial:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
var yourModule = NativeModules.YourModule;
// use it here
```

If you have the same code as in your HelloWorld.js in your module's index.js, you will then see that native modules is not empty.

If you find yourself puzzling over the ins and outs of making a module, you can simplify the process with [react-native-create-library](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library) or [react-native-create-bridge](https://github.com/peggyrayzis/react-native-create-bridge)

Comment: I was Having the same issue and Thank you so much This solution worked for me Interesting how it doesn't accept object destructuring

Answer (score -2):

If you're following the mentioned tutorial, be sure to follow it on a `react-native` project generated using `react-native init`. Using `create-react-native-app` will change the code's structure and cause issues with this.

Comment: Are those issues resolvable? What are they? It seems that this might be exactly the issue I have at the moment. But I've been working on it for a while now so re-creating the project is not really an option

Comment: @mkilmanas: I worked with react for at most a week, so I can't really help you with that.